# Android: error: cannot find symbol method getApplication()

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently imported a Eclipse project into Android Studio and have started getting this error: 
`error: cannot find symbol method getApplication()` which I wasn't getting in Eclipse from a custom adaptor:

```
public class MyAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter{

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       TextView v = new TextView(getApplication());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the error means that neither MyAdapter or SpinnerAdapter has a method called getApplication

Comment: this error should have been in eclipse aswell

Comment: doh! it was never used actively in my project in eclipse and I never deleted it even though it was broken. Eclipse never complained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get getApplication context in adapter view. you need to pass context from your activity.

like this :

youradapterclass obj = new youradapterclass(this);

and create constructor in your adapter class and save context in class variable and use it in the textview context;

see this [example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Answer (score 0):

Send the context as a parameter in MyAdapter's constructor and use it like `context.getApplication()`.

I guess U need to pass Activity instead of context to use `activity.getApplication()` .